# Create Array of Buffer in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, enums, buffer

I'm new to node.js and javascript, please let me know if you have any idea about my problem.

In node.js, I would like to create an array of binary message for comparison, and I tried two methods, both are not working.

**Method 1, something like enum**

```
var buf = new Buffer ([0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);
var a_number = {
NUMBER_1: {value: 0, msg: [0x00, 0x00, 0x00]},
NUMBER_2: {value: 1, msg: [0x01, 0x01, 0x01]},
};
```

When I try to do a buffer comparison using:

```
console.log(buf.equals (a_number.NUMBER_1.msg));
```

I got this:

```
ERROR: TypeError: Object ����
```

When I try to print content of NUMBER_1 using:

```
console.log(a_number.NUMBER_1.msg.toString ('hex'));
```

I got this:

```
0, 0, 0
```

I expected this:

```
000000
```

Finally, I give up, and try to use another method below.

**Method 2 two array**

Define a enum for array index:

```
var a_number = {
NUMBER_1: 0,
NUMBER_2: 1
};
```

Define an array of Buffer, none of below working:

```
var a_number_buf = new Buffer[] ([ [0,0,0], [1,1,1] ]);
```

or

```
var a_number_buf[] ....
```

can any expert here teach me how to do?

Comment: I tried Method 3, compare two Buffer directly 
var buf1 = new Buffer ([0, 0, 0]);
var buf2 = new Buffer ([1,1,1]);
buf1.equals (buf2);
I got same error to Method 1

node --version
0.10.38

I checked that 0.10.35 should include Buffer.equals, so I assumed that 0.10.38 should be good enough to run it, am I right?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.1.1/CHANGELOG.md

change log in node shows 0.10.35 should include this function, so I think 0.12.x is not essential

Comment: Nr 1 won't work because buf.equals expects another buffer as its argument, not an Array. Nr 2 uses Java-like Array Definition, which will not work in javascript.

Comment: thx tiger, do you have any comment about method 3 in my 1st comment note above?

Comment: are you sure that v0.10.35 already has .equals()? In your link under "Summary of changes from Node.js v0.10.35 to io.js v1.0.0" I found "added buffer.equals()"

Comment: tiger, yes, you are right, .equals may not be part of 0.10.35.  I tried to use .equalss same error message appeared.

Comment: I could use string comparison, instead of memcmp, but any one can explain, in method 1, why console.log(a_number.NUMBER_1.msg.toString ('hex')); shows string with comma character? I still hope to use a enum style to manage the buffer table

Comment: toString() on an array joins the array elements by ",", you could use a_number.NUMBER_1.msg.join("") for decimal output or a_number.NUMBER_1.msg.map(function(e) { return e.toString(16)}).join("") for hex output